# Finding an Item based on certain criteria in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table structure:

**Transaction table:**

```
code    type        action  level   id  qty   OrderID
====================================================
10005   PRODUCT     RECIPE  0       0   1     O-123  
821     VALUE_MEAL  RECIPE  0       1   1     O-123
9       PRODUCT     RECIPE  1       1   1     O-123
7093    PRODUCT     RECIPE  1       1   1     O-123
10005   PRODUCT     CHOICE  1       1   1     O-123
721     VALUE_MEAL  RECIPE  0       2   1     O-123
9       PRODUCT     RECIPE  1       2   1     O-123
7093    PRODUCT     RECIPE  1       2   1     O-123
10005   PRODUCT     CHOICE  1       2   1     O-123
```

**My Master table**:

```
code      FullName   MenuCategory 
---------------------------------
821         ML2       Group2  
721         ML1       Group2   
9           fires     Group2   
10005       Orange    Group3
```

**Expected result set:**

```
code    QTY with Meal   Sold Alone
------------------------------------
10005        2              1
```

In the expected result, we need to differentiate if an item code "10005" was sold with a VALUE_MEAL that has different level and id or it was sold alone as a PRODUCT within the same order?

Example: Code=821, contains three main sub-level which are (9, 7093, 10005) and code=721, contains three main sub-level which are (9, 7093, 10005)
so here we know 2 QTY were sold for 10005 as it's part of both VALUE_MEALS and one QTY for code = 10005 as part of standalone product

Comment: Surely you have different "value meal" combinations? If so, how do you differentiate between them in the transaction table?  You seem to have only 1 obvious "value meal" in your sample data and that does not include 10005 at all. What is your logic? And please post DDL for your tables - we need to know constraints.

Comment: So *explain* your expected results, it might be obvious to you but don't expect people to guess.

Comment: @SMor, the VALUE_MEAL is the parent that contains sub items to it, for example code = 821 contains 9, 7093 and 10005 as a sub-level for id 1

Comment: @Stu I hope you will be able to understand my logic now

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want a grouped self-join, with conditional aggregation

```sql
SELECT
  t.code,
  [QTY with Meal] = COUNT(t2.IsMeal),  -- only counts non nulls
  [Sold Alone] = COUNT(*) - COUNT(t2.IsMeal)
FROM [Transaction] t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT IsMeal =  CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END
    FROM [Transaction] t2
    WHERE t2.id = t.id
      AND t2.type = 'VALUE_MEAL'
) t2
WHERE t.code = 10005
GROUP BY
  t.code;
```

You could also switch the `COUNT(*)` in the subquery for an `EXISTS`

Answer (score 0):

For each (OrderID, code) unique pair, the query uses the 'level' column to determine whether or not items have been combined in a meal

```
select OrderID, code, 
       sum(case when [level]>0 then 1 else 0 end) [QTY with Meal],
       sum(case when [level]=0 then 1 else 0 end) [Sold Alone]
from TransactionTable
group by OrderID, code
order by OrderID, code;
```